# pyqtgraph strings in xticks overlapping each other

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I got this histogram plot:

```
import somewhere.pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import sys
pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')

class HistogramWidget(pg.PlotWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        pg.PlotWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.values = np.array([])
        self.bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
        self.brush = (0, 0, 255, 255)
        self.curve = None
        self.names = []
        self.getPlotItem().buttonsHidden = True
        self.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid gray")

    def set_bins(self, bins, names):
        self.bins = bins
        self.names = names
        self.xdict = dict(enumerate(names))
        self.getPlotItem().axes['bottom']['item'].setTicks([self.xdict.items()])

    def add_values(self, values):
        self.values = np.append(self.values, values)
        self.values = self.values.flatten()
        self.y, self.x = np.histogram(self.values, bins=self.bins)
        if self.curve is not None:
            self.removeItem(self.curve)
        self.curve = pg.PlotCurveItem(list(self.xdict.keys()), self.y, stepMode=True, fillLevel=0, brush=self.brush)
        self.addItem(self.curve)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = HistogramWidget()
    w.set_bins(np.linspace(-3, 8, 40), ['bin_'+str(i[0]) for i in enumerate(np.linspace(-3, 8, 40))])
    w.add_values(np.hstack([np.random.normal(size=500), np.random.normal(size=260, loc=4)]))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

which looks like this:

[image: histogram]

My question is: What options are there to display the xticks better?

I could just show some ticks depending on the zoom, for which I found [AxisItem.textFillLimits](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/axisitem.html), but it doesnt have any effect, where do I have to put it? This is what I tried:

```
self.getPlotItem().axes['bottom']['item'].setStyle(textFillLimits=[(0, 0.8), (2, 0.6), (4, 0.4), (6, 0.2)])
```

Ideally the xticks should be rotated by 45deg, but I did not find any clue on how to do this. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

If you give two arguments to setTicks then the first will be the major ticks and the second will be the minor tick, see the documentation http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/axisitem.html#pyqtgraph.AxisItem.setTicks

To make every other tick a minor tick you can try

```
self.getPlotItem().axes['bottom']['item'].setTicks(
                [list(self.xdict.items())[::2], list(self.xdict.items())[1::2]])
```